# Query <area> tag by HREF

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get an element in the DOM, I want a specific  tag and I am querying by a certain href.

```
<map name='image-map'>
    <area target='' alt='' title='' href='#loc=sf1d1' coords='242,50,262,67' shape='rect'>
```

I am using jQuery to grab the selector:

```
var location = '#loc=sf1d1'
var linkToDesk = document.querySelector('area[href='+location+']');
```

The error I am seeing is:

> failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document':
>   'area[href=#loc=sf1d1]' is not a valid selector.

Comment: You need to escape certain chars use `location.replace('=','\\=')` for all chars that might be a valid literal for jquery $ method

Comment: `area[href="'+location+'"]'` not `area[href='+location+']'` (need to add the double quotes " ")

Comment: You dont need double quotes if there are no double quotes in the string. Good to have but will not solve this problem

Comment: Works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/p7eoud3g/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<map name='image-map'>
     <area target='' alt='' title='' href='#loc=sf1d1' coords='242,50,262,67' shape='rect'>
</map>
```

Javascript

```
var location = '#loc=sf1d1';
var linkToDesk = document.querySelector('area[href="'+location+'"]');
console.log(linkToDesk);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape certain chars use `location.replace('=','\\=')` for all chars that might be a valid literal for jquery $ method